# How to store the return of a 2D Array

Tags: java

How can i store the return of a 2D array? For example

```
public Class A{

public String something(){
String []some_array=new String[2];
//stuff in here...sets elements of our array to something

//unsure of the next line
return some_array[];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String []some_other_array=new String[2];
A myA=new A();
//unsure of the next line
some_other_array[]=myA.something();
```

How do i go about returning the first-second element of the array that is being returned to be the first-second element of the array that i am storing it in?

Also can anyone clarify is it legal to use parameter variables from my method something() inside of it without making them equal to another variable first? I always thought you either had to declare another variable inside the method and make it equal to the parameter and use the new variable you created.

Comment: that won't compile beacuse your return type is `String` and you are returning an array of `String`

Comment: You can use parameters without assigning them to anything, they're local variables.  I... have no idea what you're asking in the first part.

Comment: Then what are the benefits of assigning them to another variable instead of using the parameters themselves directly.

Comment: @Frenchie See the code I have posted in the answer and you'll understand.

Comment: @Frenchie: there are none, that's not a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type of your method as the one shown below:

```
public String[] something(){
String []some_array=new String[2];
//stuff in here...sets elements of our arrays to something

return some_array;
}
```

Also note the return statement doesn't have `[]` brackets beside the variable `some_array`.

And in your main method you should write like this:

```
String[] some_other_array;
A myA=new A();

some_other_array = myA.something();
```

Also note in the above code that while assigning the array returned by your method to a local variable (here `some_other_array`) you don't have to use `[]` brackets.

And don't initialize your `some_other_array` variable, just make a declaration so that when you assign it the array returned by the method then it will be automatically have the size of the returned array.

Comment: He also needs to change some_other_array[]=myA.something(); to just some_other_array=myA.something();

Comment: @BryanGlazer Yes I have added it to the answer.